# What is the meaning of 'Almost perpendicular' when I asked about health

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I have asked one of my Manager, how is your health(As he was sick).

He replied *almost perpendicular*.

So what he wanted to say actually I didn't get. Can anyone tell meaning of this phrase? Thank you.

Comment: He’s getting better. He’s almost out of bed (where you lie flat, supine, *parallel to the ground*). He’s feeling well enough to stand up straight (*perpendicular to the ground*), walk around, do normal stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a joke.  If you are healthy then you can stand upright and perpendicular to the ground. So being "perpendicular" means (in this context) being in good health. But this is a deliberately odd way to say it. The idea of measuring health as an angle is quite ridiculous.

So this is a light-hearted way of saying "I'm nearly fully recovered, thank you", but with some office humour.

It is not a common or standard expression, and can only be understood in context.